# Can't obtain static method fromNative(Method, Object) from class com.sun.jna.Native

Tags: java, java-8, java-native-interface, vlc, jna

I'm using the **JNA**'s `com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary` class in order to load the `VLCJ` native library. I'm working on an `armv8(aarch x64)-based linux device`. Below is my code, **note that i am using the latest JNA version** `jna-4.5.2`:

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), Constants.DEPLIB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY);
Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
LibXUtil.initialise();
```

**First i was getting this error:**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNA native support (com/sun/jna/linux-aarch64/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path
```

After a quick search i found that i must copy the jna native lib directory from inside the jar into the jvm lib path, where the jna jar library has pre-built libraries for almost all known systems as shown in the image below:

[jna-4.5.2 internal content.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUBjD.png)

After doing that, the above exception disappeared but another one came up:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't obtain static method fromNative(Method, Object) from class com.sun.jna.Native
```

the exception is saying that it couldn't find the method **fromNative(Method, Object)** in the class **com.sun.jna.Native** however after decompiling this class i found that the method already exists.

I'm out of ideas know, any help would be highly appreiated, thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve by:

1. undo this step:

> After a quick search i found that i must copy the `jna` native lib
>   directory from inside the jar into the `jvm` lib path...

2. remove all `jna` modules (jars) from my project
3. download and link the following jars into my project:
   [`jna.jar`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/4bcc6191c5467361b5c1f12fb5797354cc3aa897/dist/jna.jar)
   [`jna-platform.jar`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/4bcc6191c5467361b5c1f12fb5797354cc3aa897/dist/jna-platform.jar)
   [`linux-aarch64.jar`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/4bcc6191c5467361b5c1f12fb5797354cc3aa897/dist/linux-aarch64.jar)

Comment: ?? Why or how does this fix it?  I'm trying to get JNA to work in Eclipse, I have the jna-5.11.0.jar and jna-platform-5.11.0.jar in my libs dir and in my build path.  Why does it matter where they are if the JVM can find them?

Answer (score 0):

If the jar files:  jna-5.11.0.jar  and jna-platform-5.11.0.jar  (or whatever version number you are using) if in you lib path (build path in Eclipse), the java command option:

**-Djna.nosys=true**

may solve the problem.  When first started, JNA is loads its own native access library and it wasn't finding it.  **jna.nosys=true** allows JNA to look in the jna-X.XX.X.jar file for what it needs.  The error message confused my because JNA seemed to be found and loaded, but it was complaining about not finding 'fromNative'.

[From JNA documentation:](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.11.0/javadoc/overview-summary.html#loading)

> ```
> Loading JNA
>
> JNA includes a small, platform-specific shared library which enables all
> native access. When the Native class is first accessed, JNA will first
> attempt to load this library from the directories specified in
> jna.boot.library.path. If that fails and jna.nosys=false is set, it will
> fall back to loading from the system library paths. Finally it will attempt
> to extract the stub library from from the JNA jar file, and load it.
>
> The jna.boot.library.path property is mainly to support jna.jar being
> included in -Xbootclasspath, where java.library.path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are
> ignored. It is also useful for designating a version of the library to use
> in preference to any which may already be installed on the system.
> ...
> ```